# GHDL: Can't find the entity in library WORK

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

When I try to analyze the testbench file this error appears (ghdl -a descodificador_tb.vhdl):

- descodificador_tb.vhdl:18:42: primary unit "descd" not found in
  library "work"

I'm learning VHDL alone and I tried to create the testbench file like I saw in examples. The code is below:

````
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity descd_tb is 
end descd_tb;

architecture behave of descd_tb is
    component descd 
        port
        (
            E, A, B: in bit;
            D0, D1, D2, D3: out bit
        );
    end component;
    
    for descod: descd use entity work.descd;
    signal E, A, B, D0, D1, D2, D3: bit;
    
begin
    descod: descd port map (E => E, A => A, B => B, D0 => D0, D1 => D1, D2 => D2, D3 => D3);
    
    process
        type pattern_type is record
        --INPUT
        E, A, B: bit;
        --OUTPUT
        D0, D1, D2, D3: bit;
        end record;
        
        type pattern_array is array (natural range <>) of pattern_type;
        constant patterns : pattern_array :=
        (('0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'),
         ('0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'),
         ('1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'),
         ('1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'),
         ('1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'),
         ('1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1'));
         
    begin 
        for i in patterns'range loop
            E <= patterns(i).E;
            A <= patterns(i).A;
            B <= patterns(i).B;
            
            wait for 1 ns;
            
            assert D0 = patterns(i).D0
              report "erro gate D0" severity error;
            assert D1 = patterns(i).D1
              report "erro gate D1" severity error;
            assert D2 = patterns(i).D2
              report "erro gate D2" severity error;
            assert D3 = patterns(i).D3
              report "erro gate D3" severity error;
        end loop;
        
        assert false report "END OF TEST" severity note;
        
        wait;
    end process;
end behave;```
````

Comment: You need to write the code for that component and add it. Please read GHDL's documentation.

Comment: In Notepad++ I wrote the code for that component, using commands "ghdl -a descodificador.vhdl" I analyze it, everything okay. Then when I wrote the testbench and analyze it this error appears.What do you mean add it? When I do these commands it should automatically add this component to work library, right?

Comment: If we had the source for the device you are testing we could see whether or not it matches the component in the TB ... has the same ports, for example. That would be one thing to check.

Comment: On what OS do you run GHDL? There are significant differences between Windows and Linux, for example, at least the last time I used it.

Comment: The message comes from the configuration specification `for descod: descd use entity work.descd;` (providing an explicit binding indication instead of relying on default binding). When analyzing descodificador_tb.vhdl the entity descd is not already found in the same working library (e.g. registered in the same work-obj93.cf). If descd had previously been analyzed into the current working library without a configuration specification  default binding would find it when elaborating the testbench.

Comment: If you compile descd into a named library (--work=name) you can add the enclosing directory to the search path for libraries (when using `library somename;`)  with the -P option. See [Invoking GHDL Options](https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/InvokingGHDL.html#options).